# JBoss Datasource constantly binding and unbinding every 5 seconds

Tags: oracle, binding, jboss, datasource

From my jboss EAP 5.1 logs I can see that the datasource is continually binding and then unbinding every 5 seconds or so... Would anyone have any idea why? I've attached my oracle-ds.xml snippet for the datasource and also the logs.

```
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>datasource</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myDB:1521:SID</connection-url>
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
<user-name>username</user-name>
<password>userpass</password>
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
<min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
<set-tx-query-timeout/>
<query-timeout>300</query-timeout>
<idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
<metadata>
    <type-mapping>Oracle10g</type-mapping>
</metadata>
```

2012-11-08 08:15:46,487 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' to JNDI name 'java:datasource'
2012-11-08 08:15:51,657 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Unbound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' from JNDI name 'java:datasource
'
2012-11-08 08:15:51,826 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' to JNDI name 'java:datasource'
2012-11-08 08:15:56,996 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Unbound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' from JNDI name 'java:datasource
'
2012-11-08 08:15:57,174 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' to JNDI name 'java:datasource'
2012-11-08 08:16:02,424 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Unbound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' from JNDI name 'java:datasource
'
2012-11-08 08:16:02,591 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' to JNDI name 'java:datasource'
2012-11-08 08:16:07,758 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Unbound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' from JNDI name 'java:datasource
'
2012-11-08 08:16:08,056 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' to JNDI name 'java:datasource'
2012-11-08 08:16:13,226 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Unbound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' from JNDI name 'java:datasource
'
2012-11-08 08:16:13,394 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' to JNDI name 'java:datasource'
2012-11-08 08:16:18,668 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (HDScanner) Unbound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=datasource' from JNDI name 'java:datasource
'

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your hot deployment scanner is "crazy". By default JBoss defines the the hotdeployment to scan for changes or new deployments every 5000 ms (5s). But it shouldn't redeploy a file if it hasn't changed from the last scan, so this behaviour is quite strange, (unless there is some kind of process that keeps changing the datasource file constantly, can you check the last modification date of the file?)

You can also try [disabling the hotdeployment scanner](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss51DisableEnableHotDeployHDScanner), or increase its scanPeriod. The scanner is set up in the file deploy/hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml. So change the scanPeriod attribute (in milliseconds), or just remove this file from the deploy directory (take care of making a backup). Notice that if you remove the file, you'll disable the hotdeployment for all the files, so to deploy new applications you'll have to restart de server or use the bin/twiddle.sh script.

On the other hand, though maybe it's not the cause of the problem, the datasource looks incomplete: remember to close the xml tags and that the root tag of a ds file is 
"datasource":

```
<datasource>
  <local-tx-datasource>
   ...
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasource>
```

I hope it will help.